# Question on the formula to calculate enthalpy change from calometric data

Tags: enthalpy, calorimetry

I have a sample question here.

"In an experiment, a student placed 20cm^3 of a solution containing 0.04 mol of HCl in a plastic cup and added 20cm^3 of solution containing 0.04 mol of Na2CO3. The highest temperature rise is 15K. If the heat capacity per unit volume of the final solution is 4.2JK^-1cm^-3, what is the enthalpy change of reaction?"

And what I calculated was:

Assuming that the density of the final solution is equal to the density of pure water, 1.00gcm^-1

∆H = (mass of final solution x heat capacity of final solution x maximum ∆Temperature)/ number of moles of the limiting reagent = (40 x 1 x 4.2 x 15)/ 0.04 = 63kJmol^-1

However, the correct answer was 126kJmol^-1.

Am I using the formula correctly here? Or is there something wrong in my calculations?

Comment: Isn't that they ask you for H of reaction? What you have calculated is the actual H change.

Comment: Sorry, it's enthalpy change of reaction to be more specific. So what I'm asking is if there's anything wrong with the formula I've used or something about my calculations.

Comment: Since you have the capacity per unit vilume, you don't need to use the density of the solution. Your answer is true. The reaction is (( carbonate + HCl ----> Hydrogencarbonate + cholorid )). Since, all HCl has consumed, the reaction won't preceed more (( I mean that Hydrogencarbonat won't react with HCl, because there is no HCl left )).
I think that the guy who computed the correct answer, has 0.02 mole as the moles of limiting reagent